# Как удалить n-элементов из массива от элемента, который содержит определенное значение?

Tags: php, массивы

Массив:

```
Array ( [0] => 123 
        [1] => 333 
        [2] => 323 
        [3] => 444 
        [4] => cas 
        [5] => sssss,XXX
       )
```

Как удалить влево 4 элемента от элемента, который содержит "XXX"?

В итоге должно остаться:

```
Array ( [0] => 123  
        [5] => sssss,XXX
       )
```

Пока пытаюсь сделать через `array_splice`, но не получается. Не могу понять как сказать, что нужно отсчитывать 4 именно от элемента в котором есть "XXX"

Comment: А что не получается с array_splice? Ошибка, неожидаемый результат?

Comment: Не могу понять как сказать, что нужно отсчитывать 4 именно от элемента в котором есть "XXX"

Comment: Добавте ваашу попытку прямо в вопрос кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/984864/edit).

Comment: Ну найдите индекс элемента XXX, а потом slice делайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве основы можете использовать следующий код:

```
$elements = [
  0 => 123,
  1 => 333, 
  2 => 323, 
  3 => 444, 
  4 => 'cas', 
  5 => 'sssss,XXX'
];

$necessaryStr = 'XXX'; //искомая строка
$position = null; // позиция искомой строки, если она есть
$numberForDel = 4; // количество элементов, которые нужно удалить
$newElements = []; // новый массив (то, что получим после избавления от ненужных         элементов, можно и без него, удалив элементы из первоначального массива)
$firstDel = 0; // индекс первого элемента для удаления

// ищем нужную нам строку
foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
  if(substr_count($value, $necessaryStr) > 0) {
    $position = $key;
    break;
  }
}

// если нашли, то 
if(!is_null($position)) {
  // корректируем индекс первого элемента для удаления
  if($position > $numberForDel) {
    $firstDel = $position - $numberForDel;
  }

  // формируем новый массив
  for($i = 0; $i <= $position; $i++) {
    if ($i < $firstDel || $i >= $position) {
      $newElements[] = $elements[$i];
    }
  }
}

// проверка
print_r($newElements);
```

Проверку на соответствие строки можно сделать строже и вместо формирования нового массива просто удалять элементы из старого (это как вам удобнее).